# How to add an icon between list rows while using .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of components that are organized in a row. When the list is wider than the window, the list wraps around to make additional rows. Is there any clean way to detect when a new row is started and add a component inbetween them?

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { ListItem } from './ListItem'

const REPORTS = [
    { id: 1, name: 'first report' },
    { id: 2, name: 'second report' },
    { id: 3, name: 'third report' },
    { id: 4, name: 'fourth report' },
    { id: 5, name: 'fifth report' },
    { id: 6, name: 'sixth report' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Kyles report' },
]

export const ReportsList = () => {

    const [reports, setReports] = useState(REPORTS)

    return (
        <div className='boxList'>{reports.map((report, index) => (
            <ListItem
                key={report.id}
                index={index}
                text={report.name}
            />
        ))}
        </div>
    )
```

This is what I have
[image: What I have]

This is what I'm trying to make
[image: What I'm trying to make]

My first guess would be to detect the size of the window, calculate how many list items can fit in a row, and run some sort of loop that loads up to that many items in a row. If there are additional items, add the separating component then load an additional row of items. Then repeat until there are no items left to list. But this feels a little overcomplicated. Is there any simpler way to go about this?

Comment: It's a pity you can't style `row-gap`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the right approach, the code is not totally ready as you might have different use cases:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [reports, setReports] = useState(REPORTS)
  const reportsElems = useRef(new Array())
  const [arrowPositions, setArrowPositions] = useState([]);
 
  const updateLayout = () => {
    // check if reportsElems.current is not empty array
    const totalElemsWidth = reportsElems.current.reduce(
      // calculate width here using offset width and gaps between
    )
    if (totalElemsWidth <= window.innerWidth) return;
    // use Math.round or anything which fits your use case
    const rowCount = window.innerWidth / totalElemsWidth
    // keep in mind the gaps if needed
    const itemsInRow = window.innerWidth / reportsElems.current[0].offsetWidth
    for (let i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
      // push new position if it's not in there already: i * itemsInRow
      setArrowPositions()
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateLayout);
    window.addEventListener('load', updateLayout);
    setArrowPositions([]);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateLayout);
      window.removeEventListener('load', updateLayout);
    }
    // update on reportsElems.current update
  }, [])

  return (
        <div className='boxList'>{reports.map((report, index) => (
            // check if arrowPositions includes index and render the icon
            <ListItem
                ref={(element) => (reportsElems.current[index] = element)}>
                key={report.id}
                index={index}
                text={report.name}
            />
        ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```